# Oauth2 does not generate the new Oauth2.json file while using youtube's API to insert videos with console

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, youtube-data-api

I want to upload videos to YouTube automatically, using the Windows console (prompt), Python codes and the Google API Youtube Data Api v3.

I created an account on the **cloud console** with a **test** email, to which I associated a **test** YouTube channel.
I downloaded the **OAuth 2.0 client ID credentials json file**, inserted it into my python code, and when I ran my python script, a *confirmation/authorization* message appeared in the prompt.

I gave the **OK** and the code created a "**.py-oauth2.json**" file.
*Everything OK.*

Now I'm trying to do the same steps with the new cloud console account and the new YouTube channel (the **final** one).
I downloaded the new OAuth 2.0 client ID credentials json file, inserted it into my python code but I get the error:

```
C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_helpers.py:255:
 UserWarning: Cannot access <myscript>.py-oauth2.json: No such file or directory
  warnings.warn(_MISSING_FILE_MESSAGE.format(filename))
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

**why? :(**
Maybe because I used the same PC for two different accounts/channels?
How can I solve it?
Maybe there is a cache to delete?